# Ubuntu focal fossa gnome performs laggy

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell

What's going on on my gnome session? it performs laggy freezing for an instant every 10 sec.

[image]

It is a fresh install on a Dell XPS 15 9750 Intel I9 equipped w/NVIDIA + 4k display.

```
$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.36.2
$ lsb_release -a       
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
$ uname -a
Linux lrkwz-XPS-15-7590 5.4.0-31-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 7 20:20:34 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ prime-select query
intel
$ gsettings get org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions
['gravatar@jr.rlabs.io', 'nvidiautil@ethanwharris', 'EasyScreenCast@iacopodeenosee.gmail.com', 'prime-indicator@gnome-shell-exstensions.fffilo.github.com', 'pixel-saver@deadalnix.me']
```

[image: processes view]

Disabling/Enabling the gnome extensions make no difference.

How can I diagnose who is the culprit?

Comment: Go to the `Processes` tab of that monitor, sort by `%SCPU` and see what processes are running/using the most CPU.

Comment: Added a processes screenshot: only gnome shell jumps up to 2 or 3 every 10sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With trial and error I found 99% the cause is MEGAsync's tray indicator

see https://github.com/meganz/MEGAsync/issues/428